# Does Facebook Pixel provide an alternative to image-based tracking?

Tags: facebook, content-security-policy, facebook-pixel

I have been asked to add Facebook Pixel tracking on to a site. 
I would ideally like to maintaining a strict CSP policy – I have some misgivings about including third-party sites given our lack of control over their content.

Ideally, I would like to avoid letting Facebook load an image on our site via our `img-src`. I can't seem to find an alternative in Facebook's Documentation. Where as, Google Analytics and some other analytical services provide alternative [transport mechanisms](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits#specifying_different_transport_mechanisms)  – namely XHR – to image-based tracking systems.

Does anyone know if there is an alternative, non-image-based, transport mechanism when using Facebook Pixel?

Comment: It doesn’t offer any options in those regards AFAIK.